# Why does some of my view disappear when the tab icon is tapped again?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

In this project, there is a tab bar. When I tap the profile tab, it takes me to the profile view in the app. This works as normal. However whilst still in the profile tab, if the profile tab is tapped again (so more than once in a row), large parts of the view disappear. Only the HStack with the image & gear shape image remain. If you tap a different tab and then go back to the profile, it works as it should.

I think this might have something to do with how I am using the onAppear method. Below is an example of how the body of the view is structured. Any ideas on why this bug is there?

```
var body: some View {
    
    ZStack {
        
        ScrollView {
                        
            VStack {
                
                HStack {
                    Image("ExampleImage")
                    
                    Button(action:{
                        self.showSettingsSheet.toggle()
                    }, label: {
                        Image(systemName: "gearshape")
                    })
                    .sheet(isPresented: $showSettingsSheet) {
                        NavigationView {
                            SettingsSheet()
                        }
                    }
                }
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                
                //NOTE: Underneth this HStack is data loaded by the .onAppear method (disappears when tab is tapped again whilst still on the tab) (The HStack above remains)
            }
        }
    }
    .onAppear {
        self.model.exampleFunction()
    }
}
```

Here is the code for my tab bar:

```
import SwiftUI

struct MainPage: View {

    @StateObject var AppModel: AppViewModel = .init()
    @Namespace var animation
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack(spacing: 0){
            
            TabView(selection: $AppModel.currentTab) {
                
                Test1()
                    .tag(Tab.Test1)
                    .setUpTab()
                
                Test2()
                    .tag(Tab.Test2)
                    .setUpTab()
                
                Test3()
                    .tag(Tab.Test3)
                    .setUpTab()
        
                Profile()
                    .tag(Tab.Profile)
                    .setUpTab()
                
                Test5()
                    .tag(Tab.Test5)
                    .setUpTab()
            }
            .overlay(alignment: .bottom) {
                CustomTabBar(currentTab: $AppModel.currentTab, animation: animation)                    
            }
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard, edges: .bottom)
    }
}
```

Comment: You should also post your tab screen code. 
Probably, you should store downloaded data in a StateObject or something to prevent it.

Comment: @MohammadRahchamani I updated the question to show the tab screen code. Could you elaborate on how I could use StateObject?